# iOS system libraries leak

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, masonry

```
Environment： iOS 7.0， Xcode 7.3.1， autolayout ＝ use "masonry"
```

High margin of error。

Do a scrollView or an UITableView through the use of masonry, then press the home button to make the app into the background, to open the app, slip quickly, there will be a memory leak and memory increase, could you tell me how to do this? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would think it's unlikely to be masonry. More likely it's something else in your app. You need to debug around where and when you create the table. Show some code. etc.